# Imagen de fondo en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero saber cómo puedo agregar una imagen de fondo en una aplicación de android studio, he leído que debe estar en la carpeta drawable; pero no se como agregar la imagen a esa carpeta. La imagen es descargada de internet.

Comment: yo intente hacer lo mismo dando un clic derecho en drawable->new->Image Asset, luego seleccioné la imagen que agregué para usar como fondo, pero de esta forma no funciona, probando de la manera que explica Matias Vidal me funcionó perfecto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ctrl + c a la imagen que quieres después Ctrl + v en la carpeta  resources >drawable.  Después en el layout de la actividad das clic, en las propiedades te vas a background y buscas la imagen (hay distintos tipos de background,  uno para poner una imagen otro para poner solo un color...) y listo!

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción es ir a la carpeta drawable desde el explorador y pegar la imagen en la carpeta drawable, después la podrás usar en cualquier View como imageView,button,etc (en la propiedad background por ej.)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar alguna imagen que tengas dentro de tus folder `/drawable` o `/mipmap` puedes copiarlas en el folder que desees:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu layout defines como fondo la imagen mediante la propiedad:

```
android:background
```

por ejemplo suponiendo una imagen llamada `android.jpg`, si la tienes almacenada dentro del directorio /drawable, usa:

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

si se encuentra dentro del directorio /mipmap, usa:

```
android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

---

por ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:background="@drawable/android"

    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

y de esta forma tendrás tu imagen de fondo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma es que te vayas a Resource Manager (View->Tool windows-Resource Manager), des clic en '+', selecciones Import Drawables seleccionas tu imagen y automáticamente se va a guardar en Drawables.